# Suggest-comment-delete feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A couple of times I've had to clarify things in comments (since that's the only communication medium), but at the end of the clarification I realized that the comments will never be useful again, but I can only delete my comments, one at a time (which doesn't bother me much), but I don't know how to ask the other party to delete their comments (other than in a comment).

So, I would suggest a feature, I would like to be able to select a number of comments (grouped together) and mark them for deletion, which would prompt the other party (parties?) in the comments to agree (or not, or some) to the deletion of their comments (the ones I've selected).

Do you think this would be useful?

Comment: What is stopping me from repeatedly requesting that you delete your comment that I don't like in an attempt to annoy you? Gotta defend against childults 'round these parts.

Comment: @TinyGiant nothing stops me from making a new comment just to annoy you, the same rules that apply to comment delivery could apply.

Comment: @TinyGiant like this, nothing stops me, but you have recourse

Comment: Yeah, but that's publicly annoying, you're explicitly asking for a method of privately annoying me.

Comment: @TinyGiant you could have an "ignore this alleged person" button at your disposal, or "report this alleged person", and the system surely knows that you received the 75th such request without answering, besides, if I already notified you to zap a comment, why would the system allow me to ask you again, I'd have to find another comment to that's related to me (my question, my answer, addressed to me, with me in the conversation?), some of these could cost a flag point, until I delete, or something, it's not impossible to make it possible to detect and spank the silly people that abuse it

Comment: What if you go through every one of my comments and mark it for deletion?

Comment: @TinyGiant You mark me for deletion? - flag me to the admins causing me to lose the feature for a month .... or some quota stops me, right now I can flag 10 things to the admins, no more, that addresses the very same problem.

Comment: You currently cannot flag a user, and I doubt that such functionality would allow me to view which user is requesting that I delete my content.

Comment: @TinyGiant this message pops up in the list, doesn't it, don't you have a preview and you can click on it. It doesn't show the user, true, but the preview can be changed, can't it? I don't know the internals of the site. But I'm already flagging you right now. With a preview.

Comment: You're flagging my comment, not me. What if I haven't commented on the post and am requesting you delete your comments? What if there are multiple other users commenting, how would you know which one was requesting the deletion?

Comment: @TinyGiant are we talking about the policy (quota+ban), the user interface (inbox+cusom preview+something vaguely like "suggest edit") or the back-end (I have no clue, add code?) ?

Comment: We're talking about implementation specifics of something that has yet to be implemented, and probably never will be. Sorry, I'm tired.

Comment: @TinyGiant as for the backend, does the suggest-edit have a field for the user? can it carry all the data for this (my-id, your-id, post-id)? Can the inbox preview have something interactive? Should it? No, it shouldn't, you should review what you're deleting, so something like "suggest edit" with a page where you can mark or unmark posts. Maybe more like the chat window? .... The policy is probably the simplest, I can agree, ignore, report. Agree gets you what you want, ignore costs quota, report calls the admins, they can take whatever action they can take already.

Comment: In response to your points in consecutive order: yes, I don't know, I don't know, I don't know, OK, huh? sure. I'm fairly uncertain as to the current location of this conversation.

Comment: @TinyGiant location? metaphysical, naturally. You're tired, I'm tired, I think we can agree it's possible and the actual implementation details are beyond what can/should be done in comments. .... Feel free to ask me to delete any of the comments :-)

Comment: Too bad there isn't a button I could click that would tell you to delete your comments without me having to tell you to delete your comments in a comment under a question about comments and the deletion of said comments in a manner similar to this comment. *drops mic*

Answer (score 10):

This already exists in the form of a comment flag.

Just flag the now useless comment with flag option "obsolete" and let someone of authority handle it.

Comment: didn't realize that, I apologize for my ignorance ... however, they way I suggested less of authority's time would be wasted, .... just a suggestion

Comment: @Martin It usually isn't wasted. These flags take lower priority and often just need a few seconds then the comments are deleted.

Comment: But one of the admins needs to take action, right? Action takes time, if it's genuinely avoidable, it's [potentially] a waste. That's my reasoning anyway. But I think you mean it's not much time, and the admins don't mind doing it. I'm only suggesting in hopes of helping.

Comment: @Martin Honestly, I don't think it's much of a burden. It doesn't take long. If you don't want to flag each individual one, you could even raise a custom flag and say 'discussion is obsolete', the request deletion of a group of comments.

Comment: I don't really mind doing it one by one, even if grouping them would be nice, I was just unaware of how it's supposed to be done, since flagging something as "obsolete" didn't quite say "do this to delete posts", at least to me, maybe it's just me, or not, maybe this could be slightly more explicitly stated for people who never did it before. The rest is just me trying to be helpful. At any rate, thanks, I'll do it this way from now on.